# generating random matrixes with genweb in a for loop

Tags: r, matrix, bipartite

I´m an R beginner and I couldn't find anything that helped me. 
I want to generate random matrices, that differ in size. i wanted to use a for-loop and the `genweb` function, but instead of many matrices it gives me back a vector.

```
library(bipartite)
zeroo <-matrix()
for(i in 10:50){
   zeroo[i]<-genweb(10, i, dens=2) 
  }
```

Comment: Try `zeroo <- lapply(10:50, function(x) genweb(10, x, dens = 2))` That will give you a list of your matrices. That is the only storage option for different size objects in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop can be changed

```
col1 <- 10:50
zeroo <- vector('list', length(col1)) #create a `list`
for(i in seq_along(col1)){
   zeroo[[i]] <- genweb(10, col1[i], dens=2) #
}

length(zeroo)
#[1] 41

zeroo[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    5    5    2    6    0    0    3    1   15     2
#[2,]    2    2    0    1    1    0    0    0    2     0
#[3,]    5    3    2    1    1    0    1    0    3     1
#[4,]    3    3    3    2    1    0    0    2    6     5
#[5,]    2    7    1    5    0    0    2    0    5     8
#[6,]    7    3    2    1    1    0    2    0    9     0
#[7,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1     0
#[8,]    4    2    3    6    0    0    0    0    6     2
#[9,]    3    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0     0
#[10,]   6    3    2    4    1    2    0    0    3     2
```